# Pusher Error: Not Found on laravel-websocket dashboard when creating event

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

I want to host a laravel-websocket server and I have been able to test it very well on localhost and it works fine. But when I hosted using Nginx and supervisor and went to the `/laravel-websockets` I am able to connect to the app and I see this

[image]

Challenge is when I

```
exception: "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException"
file: " ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php"
line: 142
message: "Pusher error: <!DOCTYPE HTML> ... Not Found .... </body>\n</html>\n."
trace: [{,…}, {,…},…]
0: {,…}
class: "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster"
file: ".../vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Dashboard/Http/Controllers/SendMessage.php"
function: "broadcast"
line: 26
type: "->"
....
}
```

Wondering what an not doing right

Comment: Have you set pusher config on .env file?

Comment: Yes I think if you mean `PUSHER_APP_ID` ,` PUSHER_APP_KEY` `PUSHER_APP_SECRET` `PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER`

Comment: So I couldn't get your point on the challenge you are facing with. could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? when do you get this error? would you be more specific?

Comment: I resolved the issue by changing the `PUSHER_APP_HOST` to another one, I think my issue  is that pusher from the front end sends the webscoket as https not was so

Comment: @iamafasha can I exactly know how did you solved the issue ? Because I am getting similar type of issue. Its says like: Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastException with message 'Pusher error:  AND inside html title it says NOT FOUND. Since all the configurations are working as is should. Only during firing event using tinker or from laravel-websockets dashboard it throws same error.